# Check if at least one field is not null Java

Tags: java, database

i'm sorry in advance in this has already been answered but i'm still new to Java and couldn't find a good solution for this.

In simple terms I want to build a search api call . It should search based on any of the not null or not empty parameters passed in the call . Now I want to check if all of the parameters are null or empty. Now the solution I have is to build methods for each type of parameter , I exemplified one for String. Is there a way to make it more elegant? Also could I make 1 method that works with all types of parameters?

```
public Page<Customer> searchCustomer(Customer customer) {

    if (
            !isNullOrEmpty(customer.getCustomerId()) && //LONG
            !isNullOrEmpty(customer.getCustomerType()) && //STRING
            !isNullOrEmpty(customer.getCustNum()) && //STRING
            !isNullOrEmpty(customer.getStatus()) && //STRING
            !isNullOrEmpty(customer.getStatusDate()) && //DATE
            !isNullOrEmpty(customer.getBalance()) && //DOUBLE
            !isNullOrEmpty(customer.getEntryDate()) && //DATE
            !isNullOrEmpty(customer.getModificationDate()) && //DATE
            !isNullOrEmpty(customer.getDeceased()) && //BOOLEAN
            !isNullOrEmpty(customer.getPreferredCommunicationsChannel()) &&

    )
```

{do query}
else {throw some message...}

```
static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s) {
    return s == null || s.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: What does it mean for a double, long, date, or boolean to be "empty"?

Comment: @Sweeper That was the question I was about to ask. Impossible unless primitve wrappers are in use on `Customer`'s members

Comment: Hi guys , sorry for the bad example . I mean empty in case of the strings , for boolean , date or long would not be the case,

Answer (score 2):

The following method does exactly what you want. It returns false if any field of `Customer` is null or empty. Unless there is a condition over here. You cannot use primitive types in your `Customer` class. Because the primitive types do not accept a `null` value. For instance, If you try to set a null value for a primitive type(`long`, `int`) you will get a `NullPointerException`. That is why you need to declare your integer, long, float, etc. values with object types(`Long`, `Integer`, `Float` etc.).

Updated: This method search for all, kind of objects(not just for customer)

```
  public boolean checkIfAnyFieldIsNullOrEmpty(Object object) {
        // Get all fields of the object
        Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        // Loop through each field and check if it's null or empty
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                Object fieldValue = field.get(object);
                if (fieldValue == null || fieldValue.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // Handle exception as needed
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // All fields are not null or empty
        return true;
    }
```

Now you can call this method such that.

```
boolean addFlag =  checkIfAnyFieldIsNullOrEmpty(address);
boolean cusFlag =  checkIfAnyFieldIsNullOrEmpty(customer);
boolean arrFlag =  checkIfAnyFieldIsNullOrEmpty(arrangement);

boolean result = addFlag && cusFlag && arrFlag;

if(result) {
//query
}
```

or you can write a method of that and make `checkIfAnyFieldIsNullOrEmpty` method private. Allow only the use of following method.

```
   public boolean checkFields(Customer c, Address d, Arrangement a){
        boolean addFlag =  checkIfAnyFieldIsNullOrEmpty(a);
        boolean cusFlag =  checkIfAnyFieldIsNullOrEmpty(c);
        boolean arrFlag =  checkIfAnyFieldIsNullOrEmpty(a);

        return addFlag && cusFlag && arrFlag;
    }
```

Comment: Hi , Thank you ! And if I would want to add multiple tables ? For instance I want to do a join left on my query , and i would want to also have this for table addresses or payment ? public Page<Customer> searchCustomer( Customer customer, Address address, PaymentArrangement paymentArrangement) ) throws IllegalAccessException { ... 

Could I make a method that i pass what field i want and cycle through it ? and call the method 3 times for each of my 3 fields?

I'm new to fields .

Comment: As far as I understand you are trying to search for those tree tables. And you want to search those tables with one method, right?

Comment: I mean to pass something like :

        boolean isNotNullOrEmpty = checkCustomerFields(customer, address, paymentArrangement);
        if (isNotNullOrEmpty) {query...

Comment: @FlorinGiorgian the answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is regarding the type of the arguments, then just use Object. To check if it is an empty String, you can use instanceof and then cast it to String:

```
static boolean isNullOrEmpty(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof String){
        return obj == null || ((String) obj).isEmpty();
    }
    return obj == null;
}
```